# C# Remoting IPC, how to test if remote application is running?

Tags: c#, .net, remoting, ipc

Good morning everyone!

I'm doing a distributed application using .NET 4.0, C# and Remoting (IPC at the moment but that may change, Object is **WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton**).

Upon startup of the client I'd like to test whether the server is up and running.

What would be the best practice to implement this? Call any one method? Implement a special method just for that startup test?

At the moment I start the client and it then calls methods on the server periodically (every 100 ms). That causes the client to show an estimated 1,000,000,000 error dialogs pointing out that the server is unreachable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably use a global mutex.

Comment: I'd like to find a way that also works when I switch to TCP/IP and "real" remoting one day.